# Flatten multiple arrays keeping order

Tags: json, jq, flatten

I have a json object like:

```
{
  "Nemo": [
    3694756688,
    3694756832,
    3694756650
  ],
  "Firefox": [
    3694756795,
    3694756407,
    3694756412,
    3694756395
  ],
  "Codium": [
    3694756035,
    3694756383,
    3694756378
  ],
  "Terminals": [
    3694756804,
    3694756802,
    3694756428
}
```

I need output like:

```
3694756688
3694756832
3694756650
3694756795
3694756407
3694756412
3694756395
3694756035
3694756383
3694756378
3694756804
3694756802
3694756428
```

The order is important. How can i do it with jq.

Comment: Relying on the order of elements of an object is a bug. JSON says `{ "Nemo": [], "Firefox": [] }` and `{ "Firefox": [], "Nemo": [] }` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keys_unsorted` gives you the keys in their original order. You can use them to iterate:

```bash
.[keys_unsorted[]][]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8_d6ah9aSpM)

You could also just use `.[]` to iterate over the object's fields, which for current versions of jq produces the same result, but that is not guaranteed to stay that way:

```bash
.[][]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2gP_nS-jXtn)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following filter :

```
.Nemo[],.Firefox[],.Codium[],.Terminals[]
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/HiISncDcv9Z).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/indjWd60xVV)):

```
cat your_file.json | jq -r "map(values) | flatten | .[]"
```

Prints:

```
3694756688
3694756832
3694756650
3694756795
3694756407
3694756412
3694756395
3694756035
3694756383
3694756378
3694756804
3694756802
3694756428
```

---

Or just simply ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jPov74OLTRG)) thanks @pmf:

```
cat your_file.json | jq "flatten[]"
```

Comment: Why not just `... | jq 'flatten[]'`?

Comment: @pmf Yeah, that's more elegant solution! Thanks for suggestion. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: There are two accepted answer here. I can not accept both so I upvoted your answer.